# visual studio Find Replace

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, replace

I have lots of source code files. I have lots of hard coded string. I want find/replace some words from **C/C++ strings only**.

for example.
I have source code like

```
log_msg_w(LOG_ERR, "string1"); 
log_msg_w(LOG_ERR, "string");
```

i want to find/replace and make the code like this

```
log_msg_w(LOG_ERR, _T("string1") );
log_msg_w(LOG_ERR, _T("string") );
```

I hope this is clear. I want to replace only strings in c/c++ code and keep other codes untouched. This was always a problem for me.

**I read regular expression can help in this regard.**

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the standard search and replace?  It should be able to handle this, unless this exact code appears in other code (which would be strange indeed).

Comment: Standard find/replace is not sufficient. It would be great if you suggest something

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2125503/220636

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file where the replacement should be done. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the "Find and Replace" dialog. In *"Find what:"* text box type **{\"[^\"]*\"}**, it searches all the strings in double quotation marks. In *"Replace With:"* text box type **_T(\1)**. \1 means to use the matched pattern enclosed in curly braces. Check *"Use:"* check box and select "Regular expressions" from the combo box. Uncheck *"Match case"* & *"Match whole word"* check boxes. Finally press *"Replace All"*.

To replace the strings in `log_msg_w`, you just need to correct the search and replace patterns to **log_msg_w(LOG_ERR, {\"[^\"]*\"});** and **log_msg_w(LOG_ERR, _T(\1));** respectevely

Comment: this is a good starting point, but it will replace _all_ quoted strings, the author only wants to replace those in the log_msg_w call I presume

Comment: If you need to replace the strings in `log_msg_w`, you just need to a little bit correct the search and replace patterns to **log_msg_w\(LOG_ERR, {\"[^\"]*\"}\);** and **log_msg_w(LOG_ERR, _T(\1));** respectevely

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use Expression Builder, after checking on "Use: Regular Expressions" in Find And Replace menu, by pressing right arrow right next to the "find what" combo box.

In order to find a string in quotes, there is an expression :q

You should write
In Find What:
log_msg_w(LOG_ERR, (_T()*{:q}())#

In Replace With:
log_msg_w(LOG_ERR, _T(\1))

A comprehensive list of all macros of VS Editor regular expressions is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)