# RegEx in Visual Studio Find and Replace dialog

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've a large c++ project and I want modify all files of my project that have:

```
expression(expression...)
```

into

```
expression( expression... )
```

same for `expression[expression]` `expression[ expression ]`

I can capture `(expression` but i don't know how to make the replace.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. Does somebody have a suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Just use \1 .. \8 (\9 does not work for some reason) for the captured matches

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125503/visual-studio-find-and-replace-regular-expressions-help

Comment: thank you I've to search for {[(]}{[a-zA-Z]+}{[)]} and replace with \1 \2 \3

Comment: I've refined to search: {[:a]*}{[(]}{[:a'"]+}{[)]}{[:a]*} replace with \1\2 \3 \4\5